# Remove Title from Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I want to remove the view that is allocated for the title in a contextual action bar.

[image: This is what I want to remove]

Please note that I do not want to set the title; I want the `View` entirely gone. This is to allow more room so that actions can be displayed on the menu bar rather than being dropped into the overflow menu.

Also note that I do not want to set `android:showAsAction="always"`. I want Android to decide how much space there is for the icons. I just want there to **be more space** by removing the blank area that is reserved for a title.

**UPDATE**

Things I have tried:

- `ActionMode.setCustomView(null)`
- `ActionMode.setTitleOptionalHint(true)`
- `ActionMode.setTitle("")`.

Unfortunately, none of these have worked.

---

**UPDATE 2**

It turns out my desired results are impossible to achieve in the way I was attempting. Removing the title will not allow room for more icons; Android sets a hard limit based upon the device screen size. If you are wanting to add more icons to the menu, see the answer provided by @adneal.

If you actually have a title (as shown below) and want to remove it, then you can call `ActionMode.setTitle("")`, as provided by @CommonsWare in the accepted answer.

[image: Example of a menu with a title]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `setCustomView(null)` on the `ActionMode`.

If that does not work, try `setTitleOptionalHint(true)` on the `ActionMode`.

If that does not work, try `setTitle("")` on the `ActionMode`.

Comment: I tried calling these after calling `inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);` within `onPrepareActionMode`. Is that the appropriate place to try these?

Comment: It means I added those lines to my code and ran the app, but the problem persists.

Comment: @DirtyBeach: `onPrepareActionMode()` would certainly seem to be the right spot. Sorry that these did not work.

Comment: According to the comments made by @adneal, it seems this is the proper way to remove the title. Unfortunately, it did not produce the desired results because of the icon limit. Hence, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Also note that I do not want to set android:showAsAction="always"

You have to if you want more than two action buttons in the `ActionBar`, at least on smaller screens. The [ActionBarPolicy](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/ActionBarPolicy.java#L43) determines how many action button to place in the `ActionBar` and the [default amount is 2.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/6b8a3a52acf1c2722551f1ea1ce47831f87939cd/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml#L31)

The only way to override that default value is to make your `MenuItem` "always" appear.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            menu.add("Item " + (i + 1)).setIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: While that does help, it does not answer the question "How do I remove the `View` containing the title?" I'm starting to think that it may actually not be there. But, as you've pointed out, Android basically says, "I don't care if there's space; you only get two icons. Deal with it."

Comment: Set your menu items to "always" show, then use the answer @CommonsWare provided. I didn't mention how to remove the title because he's already provided pretty much every possible solution to that.

Comment: That definitely works; any icon that has the attribute `android:showAsAction="always"` is forced into the menu, as your screenshot shows. I was hoping removing the title view would allow more space without doing that. Unfortunately, it seems that is not the case.

Comment: I was hoping removing the title view would allow more space

Answer (score 2):

Following adneal's answer I ran into problem how to deal with the action.
so I found this solution simpler:
 still using the `xml/inflater` but add

```
 menu.findItem(R.id.whatever).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ovrride
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState……

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.prva.xml);
```

Comment: This is for the action bar within an `Activity`. I am asking about the contextual action bar within an `ActionMode`. They are different things.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions provided here and made some observations:

- The view for the title is always contained in the view-hierachy (-> Layout Inspector from Android Studio) But it is in the background and will be overridden by the content.
- setContentView adds the view provided to the layuot (in the foreground). So `setContentView(null)` does not remove the view for the title. (Still visible in the Layout Inspector)
- `app:showAsAction="always"` is overridden when inflating the layout. You can set 3 items to be always displayed but only 2 items will be displayed.

But setting `.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)` programmatically after inflating the menu works.