# Android - How to hide Context Menu Title?

Tags: android, contextmenu, title

I would like to remove the Context Menu Title so that I can show more menu items on the bar. Search quite a bit, tried setTitleOptionalHint and other stuff but in vain. Appreciate your help in sharing with me with way to achieve this.

I tried the methods listed in this link but did not work -
[Remove Title from Contextual Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253475/remove-title-from-contextual-action-bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Title from Contextual Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253475/remove-title-from-contextual-action-bar)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried all three but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show more context menu items, set their setShowAsAction to Always after inflating the context menu (at run time). Fromm what I have seen, only this works.